# Symbol of quintal

Tags: mass, conventions, notation, units, metrology

Depending on the source, I have come across the symbol of [quintal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quintal) as 'q', 'qt'and 'qtl'. Is there a standard symbol for quintal. If yes what is it?

Comment: Do you mean the unit of weight? If so that isn't a unit used in physics.

Comment: No, quintal is a unit used for mass. It is equal to 100kg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the term "quintal" is inherited from French language, the 'official' symbol would be the one given by the French 'Imprimerie Nationale' in its book about typographic rules and conventions (available [here](https://www.circaete.net/eric/Lexique%20des%20r%C3%A8gles%20typographiques%20en%20usage%20%C3%A0%20l%27Imprimerie%20nationale.pdf), beware it's quite a big book and it's all in French obviously...). Anyway, that symbol is q for the quintal.

Nevertheless, as the quintal is not an official unit from the international system, there is apparently no official symbol given by any international convention, so depending on the context, don't hesitate to define what a quintal is (and its symbol) before using it.